# Scope and angular material

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material

Sorry for the lengthy question. I have created a md- bottomsheet using angular material. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet. This button triggers the bottomsheet.

html file 1:

```
<md-button ng-click="openBottomSheet()"></md-button>
```

This is the function i trigger

JS - controller 1

```
$scope.openBottomSheet = function () {

    $mdBottomSheet.show({
        templateUrl: 'components/map/services.html',
        disableBackdrop: true,
        controller: 'serviceController',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
    });
};
```

Inside my bottom sheet i've created switch-buttons https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/switch that triggers a function. I have another function that closes the bottomsheet.

```
<md-bottom-sheet class="md-list servicebottomsheet" layout-align="center center" class="mapoptionwrap" ng-cloak>
<div class="tester">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <button ng-click="closeBottomSheet()">
            <i class="material-icons closeservice">clear</i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" ng-repeat="option in mapoptions" class="scrolltest">

        <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">


            <p class="servicetexts">{{option.title | translate}}</p>
        </div>
        <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="testing" aria-label="Switch 1" ng-click="switchFilter(option)">
        </md-switch>


    </div>
</div>
```

These are the functions that are triggered

controller nr 2

```
app.controller("serviceController", ['$scope', 'mapFilters', '$mdBottomSheet', function ($scope, mapFilters, $mdBottomSheet) {
$scope.mapoptions = mapFilters.getMapFilters();
$scope.switchFilter = function (mapoption) {
    mapFilters.filter[mapoption.type] = !mapFilters.filter[mapoption.type];
    console.log(mapFilters.filter);
}

$scope.closeBottomSheet = function () {
    $mdBottomSheet.hide({
        preserveScope: true,
    });

}
}])
```

When I press the switches I trigger the switchfilter function that sets a variable from false to true. It works just fine, exactly as it should. However when i close the bottomsheet, and then reopen it the switches seem to have been emptied, all set to false again, although the booleen that I changed with the switch is still set to true. Why is this? Does it have something to do with my scope since i'm using different controllers?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. If you don't specify a scope in your config it will create a new one every time you open the bottomsheet, and destroy it whenever you close it.

You could create your bottomsheet like this:

```
$scope.openBottomSheet = function () {
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
        templateUrl: 'components/map/services.html',
        disableBackdrop: true,
        controller: 'serviceController',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        scope: $scope,
        preserveScope: true
    });
};
```

Doing this you'll pass in your parent scope (you could pass any scope), and with `preserveScope: true` it won't destroy the scope once you close the bottomsheet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I thought this solution would work but it doesn't. Seems like nothing I add when I create the bottomsheet, not even the "clickOutsideToClose" works. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Interesting. You added it to the `show` function's `config`, right? Looking at your question, the `hide`method shouldn't have any parameters like that. I can create a fiddle if needed.